# What happens if the call to `kill` causes the signal to be generated for the calling process and the signal is not blocked?

Tags: linux, signals, kill

[Advanced Programming Unix Environment](https://books.google.com/books?id=_kpsAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA338&dq=If%20the%20call%20to%20kill%20causes%20the%20signal%20to%20be%20generated%20for%20the%20calling%20process%20and%20if%20the%20signal%20is%20not%20blocked%2C&pg=PA338#v=onepage&q&f=false) says:

> ```
> #include <signal.h>
> int kill(pid_t pid, int signo);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If **the call to `kill` causes the signal to be generated for the
>   calling process** and if **the signal is not blocked**, either `signo` or
>   some other pending, unblocked signal is **delivered to  the  process 
>   before kill returns**.  (Additional conditions  occur  with  threads; 
>   see Section 12.8 for more information.)

I have some trouble understanding the above paragraph.

What does the description of the case mean

- "the call to `kill` causes the signal to be generated for the calling process"
- "the signal is not blocked"?

What does the result mean?

Would someone rephrase and/or give some example?

Answer (score 2):

All this is saying is that if the process is using `kill` to send a signal to itself, then that signal will be delivered before `kill` returns.  With some caveats.

Comment: Thanks. In "either signo or some other pending, unblocked signal ", why does it mention "some other pending, unblocked signal", instead of just the signal specified in the `kill()` call?

Comment: @Tim if there is a signal pending, that signal will be delivered first.

Comment: Do you mean both the signal sent by `kill()` and any pending signal will be delivered? If yes, what does the quote says "either ... or ..."? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490899/how-is-some-other-pending-unblocked-signal-involved-when-a-process-sends-a-si#comment900734_490905

Comment: Possibly both signals will be delivered.  Perhaps the signal handler for the first will cause the process to terminate, or perhaps it will modify the signal handling disposition, or perhaps some other situation occurs.  (Signal handling is notoriously fickle.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the uses of **kill** is to send s signal to a program telling that program to end - that where the name comes from. However, nowadays, there are several other signals you can send a program.

Basically, when one program calls kill with the pid (process id) of a different program, it is telling the kernel to pass that signal to the other program.

That doesn't always mean that the signal will be sent to the other program. For instead, if the program calling kill runs with a different user than the program bring signaled, the kernel will not pass the signal, and block it instead.